Given a distribution function, can the random variable be determined from it?
We know that a random variable is given, then its distribution function can be determined.
Question: if the distribution function is given, can the random variable be determined from it?
Can someone answer this or prove this to me?

If you define a random variable on the flip of a coin, with $X$ equal to  $+1$ on heads and $-1$ on tails, and $U=-X,$ $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution but different values.

You need to define random variable, but essentially the answer is no, because different random variables can have the same distribution.
For example, throw two fair six-sided dice, one red and the other green.  The numbers showing are random variables, each with a uniform distribution on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, but they are likely to show different values most of the time.  So knowing the distribution does not tell you which of the two dice you are looking at.
You would come to the same answer if your definition of a random variable was a measure-theoretic function $\Omega \to \mathbb R$, as you could have $X_1$ and $X_2$ with the same distribution, i.e. $\mathbb P(\omega \in \Omega: X_1(\omega) \in S) = \mathbb P(\omega \in \Omega: X_2(\omega) \in S)$ for all measurable $S \subset  \mathbb R$, but being different random variables in the sense that $\mathbb P(\omega \in \Omega: X_1(\omega) \not= X_2(\omega))>0$.

I agree with everything, but you seem to be implying that your second paragraph is different from the third. I would say that the values on the two dice are also measure-theoretic functions $\Omega \to \mathbb R$, just specified less formally - no?

@MishaLavrov I do not disagree with you, but my second paragraph was really aimed at people who did not see random variables as functions from some possibly infinite sample space.

I love this answer, but want to make the last sentence explicit. Let $\Omega = {S, T}, X_1(S) = 1; X_1(T) = 0; X_2(S) = 0; X_2(S) = 1$, and assign probability $0.5$ to each of $S$ and $T$. Then for any measurable $S \subset \mathbb R$ (indeed, any $S$) we have $P(\omega\in \Omega : X_1(\omega) \in S) = P(\omega\in \Omega : X_2(\omega) \in S)$. But ${\omega\in \Omega : X_1(\omega) \ne X_2(\omega)} = \Omega$, hence has probability $1$.

Even if I tell you what kind of random experiment I'm doing, the answer is no.
For example, suppose I tell you that I flip five fair coins and use them to compute a random variable $\mathbf X \sim \text{Binomial}(n=5, p=\frac12)$; that is, I tell you that the distribution of $\mathbf X$ is given by $\Pr[\mathbf X = k] = \binom 5k (\frac12)^5$ for $k=0,1,\dots,5$. (You could also specify $\mathbf X$ by the CDF if you wanted to.)
You have no way to use this information to tell whether $\mathbf X$ counts the number of times I flipped heads, or the number of times I flipped tails, or even some other more unnatural option.

The short answer is: no.
The simplest example I can think of is to flip a fair coin, which comes up heads with probabiltiy $1/2$. Now, suppose I have two indicator random variables that essentially "relabels" the coin flip:
$$ I_H = \begin{cases} 1, &Heads \\ 0, &Tails \end{cases} \qquad I_T = \begin{cases} 1, &Tails \\ 0, &Heads \end{cases} $$
$I_H$ and $I_T$ have the same distribution: they both take value $0$ or $1$ with probability $1/2$. However, $I_H$ and $I_T$ are never equal. In fact, whenever $I_H = 1$, $I_T = 0$, and vice versa.
Now, if somebody says that there is a random variable $X$ that takes value $0$ or $1$ both with probability $1/2$, i.e. the distribution is given, it is impossible for me to determine if it is $I_H$ or $I_T$. Even given this coin flipping experiment/scenario, the "labeling" still matters.

It is often useful to think of random variables intuitively as "labels". In fact, that's what they are. Random variables are mappings from sample space $\Omega$ (with a corresponding probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$) to some target space $E$ with $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{E}$. With these definitiond, $X$ and $Y$ are equal in distribution just means for every set $A \in \mathcal{E}$, $\mathbb{P}\{X^{-1}A\} = \mathbb{P}\{Y^{-1}A\}$. The mappings themselves need not be the same.
Intuitively, equal in distribution is, for every possible "label" assigned by $X$ and $Y$, the probability of $X$ assigning this label is equal to the probability of $Y$ assigning the same label.
